# BIRT report not running in web viewer

Tags: birt

I am designing reports in BIRT designer. When I try to preview the report or run as html, the report seems fine. However, when I try to run the report in report viewer (which opens in IE or firefox), it does not seem to work. Please check the attached image

[image: Opening the report in viewer]

[image: then is how IE shows the report]

the above report was when it needed a prompt/parameter/filter. When I try to run a report without any parameter..a simple chart..I get the following error

[image: Running a simple chart in IE]
Can someone please tell me how to fix this

Regards
Syed

Comment: Did you install a web viewer like Apache Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: I haven't installed BIRT viewer and Apache. I believe that if eclipse Birt designer is running, then we can runt the report in web viewer?

Comment: I don't have BIRT without a related Apache viewer, but I do have BIRT on a server without Excel.  If I try to view report as XLS It will not work.  I get a different error.

Answer (score 3):

I was just going to leave this as it is, considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620052/7601057) already has a very helpful link, but since this question was asked long ago and I just faced the same problem, as well as some of my colleagues, I'm going to elaborate on this further.

Birt Web Viewer, so far, **doesn't work with Java 8**. You have to **use Java 7, or inferior**. So, go to Oracle's [JRE 7 download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) and install the appropriate version. Remember it has to be the same version as your Eclipse (x86 Eclipse with x86 JRE 7; x64 Eclipse with x64 JRE 7).

After that, you'll have to add a Path System Variable pointing to Java 7's bin folder. To do this, right click on "My Computer", select "Properties", select "Advanced System Configurations" and click on "Environment Variables". In "System Variables", double click on the "Path" option. Edit "Variable Value" by including  the path to JRE 7 bin (such as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`, for example). Remember to separate this variable from the others with a semicolon!

This System Variable part is a bit confusing, but you can check videos of it in case of doubt, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6NeRfcJtdU).

Finally, try to run the report on Web Viewer again. If it works, great! If not, continue reading.

In case the viewer appears without errors, but empty, you can try to run it using your computer's navigator (Firefox, Chrome...).

To do this, go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser and tick "Use external web browser". You can select which browser you want to use on the options below. After that, go to Window -> Preferences -> Report Design -> Preview and tick "Always use external browsers".

To give credit where is due, I figured all of this by using [this forum on Eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/739682/), that I found out by myself as well as was sugested by [David Flam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620052/7601057).

Answer (score 1):

Syed,

I was having exactly the same problem. After a little research, I found this:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/739682/

After I removed Java 8 and installed Java 7 on my machine, Birt Web Viewer started successfully.