# Eclipse and BIRT Error - View Report in Web Viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I am using Eclipse 4.3 Kepler with BIRT 4.3.2 on a 64-bit machine running Windows 7 and Java 8.

When I select Run -> View Report -> In Web Viewer the following error message is displayed:



**HTTP ERROR: 500**
***Problem accessing /viewer/frameset. Reason:***

**Server Error**

**Powered by Jetty://**


This happens even with a simple "Hello World" report that contains only static (ie non-dynamic) content.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Seriously! Whenever I get this Error, I restart Eclipse and it works. While the Report is loading you should not interact with Eclipse and simply wait.

Comment: What web viewer are using?

Comment: I have tried this multiple times, on 6 separate machines with similar environments - Windows-7 64-bit + Kepler + Java 8 - and I always get the same error message. As for which web-viewer, the "Web Browser" in Preferences -> General is set to "Use internal web browser". (It makes no difference if I select an external browser.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a problem with the "View Report" Option where the internal Jetty Server does not work with Java 8.

Downgrading to Java 7 worked fine. In Java 8 you have to use the View Report as option e.g. View Report as Doc.

See also here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/739682/
There is a bugzilla entry, unfortunatly with no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check Data source.

I get same error when i try to run the report taken from the server having only DB driver class and JNDI URL and having blank in DB URL, Username and Password.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you have not installed a web viewer like Apache Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org

In much the same way that you can not open a BIRT report as Excel on a machine without Excel. you can not open as a web page without a web viewer.

I put some similar comments on the question [BIRT report not running in web viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616140) but the OP has not followed through.

**Work in progress, attempting to recreate a functional system that matches a working version (4.2.0).**

- From the server you are installing on (i.e. MyServerDEV04)
- Create a new version of the application go to http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

  - Download the current version (i.e. 4.3.2 'All-in-One', Windows 64 BIT)
  - Create to (save as, or copy to after opening) new file "C:\Program Files\eclipse-All-In_One4_3_2
- Install Apache Tomcat from http://tomcat.apache.org/

  - Download the current version (i.e  7.0 .53 64 BIT)
  - Create to (save as, or copy to after opening) new files "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0.53"
  - Do a md5 checksum? **NO**; Windows does not have the tool you can get it here https://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290/en-us but not probably not worthwhile for a single event
  - It looks like for Windows, it is pretty easy. Downloading 7.0 .53 now .
  - Looks like windows-x64.zip is the correct file
  - Create to (save as, or copy to after opening) new files ""C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0.53"
- Install Driver For BIRT

  - You can get the most current 'Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server' at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx
  - C:\Program Files\eclipse-All-In_One4_3_2\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_4.3.1.v201308301349\drivers
  - C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Birt\WEB-INF\lib
  - Apache file will not exist until you open BIRT for the first time.
- Check that you have both 32 & 64 bit Java is installed http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

  - I was browsing with a 32 bit, installing 64 BIT did not give a good test, but it did over come the Java issue BIRT was complaining about.
- Launch BIRT -

  - Launch using C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0.53\webapps\Birt as the workspace
  - Open workbench
- Next step is set up house then testing.

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure Eclipse/BIRT to use a local instance of Tomcat for this purpose?

Comment: In my case my birt is running on a server. I have working versions that where put in production without "how to notes" so I am actively attempting to recreated good notes, and get if up on running on my DEV server. Adding what I have but this is a work in progress.  There are lots of varialbes and I have not tested my web view yet.